# What are some functions that take a long time to execute?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have written a c++ program for my homework that calculates the time it takes to run a function, and I need some time consuming functions to execute, at least a couple seconds for a computer to run it, and preferably if it's a matrix. All the functions I'm trying to run runs in a second or less and it's frustrating.

and it can't leave a giant mess on the screen with characters, like a 1000 x 2000 matrix

I've been told that squaring a matrix will take some time for the computer to do but I don't know if it's true or how it's done.

This is my current matrix, which loads up in less than a second :(

```
#include <iostream>
#define HEIGHT 10
#define WIDTH 20
using namespace std;

void func()
{
    char world[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++ ) {
            world[i][j] = '.';
            cout << world[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my experience, functions that contain infinite loops take a long time to execute.

Comment: You would like to measure running time of a function or what?

Comment: Just put in a [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: In all seriousness, the "standard" approach is to throw a loop over any function and run enough iterations so that it takes long enough.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg thanks man i just used the sleep function it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given any function `f` that does not have side effects, you can make `f2` 1 million times less efficient by

```
void f2() { for( long i = 1;  i <= 1000000; ++i ) { f(); } }
```

Now if that isn't slow enough, whooooosh!, here comes `f3`,

```
void f3() { for( long i = 1;  i <= 1000000; ++i ) { f2(); } }
```

And so on.

But if you want *really* really inefficient, then look up the Ackermann function.

---

That said, note that the above approach essentially amounts to executing whatever you want to measure, enough times.

And that's the standard approach.